# Chromecast embedded youtube video on iOS

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, google-cast, chromecast

I am developing an app for iOS.I am embedding Youtube videos in UIWebView using javascript youtube player API (YT.Player).

I checked link, https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/2995235?hl=en. And it is mentioned, 
**Casting from YouTube is supported from the YouTube app, YouTube.com, and most embedded YouTube videos.**

I wanted to know, can I handle chromecast of embedded youtube that is integrated to my UIWebView? If so, how? I do not want to integrate Google cast SDK and keep track of all chromecast devices in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - that your case isn't currently supported. Unfortunately, you need the Chrome Extension to make those YouTube cases work, and that isn't supported in a UIWebView on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

In our Android application, we integrate youtube videos using YouTubePlayer APIs.
<https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer>

Just wanted to know what is the better approach to handle chromecast of youtube videos from Android application? However I do not want to keep track of chromecast devices in my app.